# Transform XML to use as training set for Named Entity Recognition (NER)

Tags: xml, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf

I would like to leverage structured information I have in the form of XML to train a CRF model for the Stanford NLP package. The XML looks something like:

```
<dates>
   <date>Advance Access publication on 
      <month>July</month>
      <day>11</day>, 
      <year>2007</year>
   </date>
</dates>
```

According to http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a I could use

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer sample.xml > date.tok
```

to get my tokens. But how could I leverage the XML encapsulation to automatically tag my tokens with the appropriate class?

Is there such a support/process in the Stanford NLP package, or should I rather go about writing my token file by hand (using XSLT for example)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this XML format. If it is a common standard, you might be able to find a converter — you want to convert into "IO" or "IOB" encoding, which is what Stanford NER works with. Otherwise, you'll have to do it manually.

Here's an example of IO encoding: there is one word per line, each with a corresponding NER tag. This tag is either "O" (no label) or some specific NER label. Note that sentences are separated by a blank line.

```
I   O
complained  O
to  O
Microsoft   ORGANIZATION
about   O
Bill    PERSON
Gates   PERSON
.   O

They    O
told    O
me  O
to  O
see O
the O
mayor   O
of  O
New LOCATION
York    LOCATION
.   O
```